# How do I run a spark application on a tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7, spark-framework

After a day of googling, I'm still lost.

I've created a Spark web-application that runs on the embedded Jetty server, but I want to run my web-application on a Tomcat server.

I'm using Maven to build my web-application and can't find any good resources on using Spark on Tomcat with Maven.

How can I create a Maven project with Spark and run it on a Tomcat server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement [EmbeddedServer](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/master/src/main/java/spark/embeddedserver/EmbeddedServers.java) interface in order to do it. Currently, it only supports Jetty by default. So, fork it and submit a PR to the author.

Comment: They have docs on the Spark site about using it with maven and tomcat, but they're too broad. BTW, I'm talking about the Spark Micro-Framework not Apache Spark.

Comment: I've checked the code before answering, don't be shy to take a look into sources. You'll learn much more than just reading docs. 
Take a look at the package in the most recent branch of the Spark.
https://github.com/perwendel/spark/tree/master/src/main/java/spark/embeddedserver

It doesn't have tomcat support for now, unless someone would implement it.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I appreciate the accurate answer!

Comment: You can to run Spark Application in Tomcat Server implements the interface spark.servlet.SparkApplication.  And add the configuracion in the web xml.